# Copy and paste specific columns in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy columns (A, C, D, Q:T) in one sheet and paste them to another.

When I paste column B also pastes to the other sheet. I didn't select B.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdselectfile_Click()
    Dim Filepath As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Filepath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files, *.xls, All files (*.*), *.*", Title:="Please select a file...")
    If VarType(Filepath) = vbString And Filepath <> Empty Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filepath)       'active file
        Union(Columns("A:A"), Columns("C:D"), Columns("Q:T")).Select
        Selection.Copy
        wb.Close
        With ThisWorkbook
             Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")
             ws.Columns("A:G").PasteSpecial
        End With
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "Incorrect Input, Please select the file again"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: how do you want the columns to be pasted?

Comment: paste them in the current worksheet from columns A:G

Comment: Ok, this is what the code does. Your code works for me just fine so I don't understand where the problem is

Comment: It works fine on my system too. Column B will be populated of course since you select it as destination.

Comment: I don't want to copy the column B, but the content was pasted when I paste them in destination

Comment: @user3804820 are you sure you are looking at the correct sheet (`data`) after pasting?

Comment: @mehow yes, it works fine at first, then it just went wrong

Comment: the column B shouldn't be copied. In fact, the whole sheet was copied

Comment: thats not possible with your current code.. im confused here... Start a new workbook and run the most minimal example of your code ...`Union(Columns("A:A"), Columns("C:D"), Columns("Q:T")).Copy` then `Sheet2.Columns("A:G").PasteSpecial` and verify the behaviour

Comment: I'm also confused. I checked the copied sheet after debugging, the columns selected were correct, but the in destination it pasted everything. @mehow

Comment: @user3804820 [**STEP THROUGH CODE**](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: I know where went wrong now, it copied the whole sheet. But how's that happen?  @mehow

Comment: If I don't close the workbook(delete wb.close), it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try this code...

```
Private Sub cmdselectfile_Click()
    Dim Filepath As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Filepath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files, *.xls, All files (*.*), *.*", Title:="Please select a file...")
    If VarType(Filepath) = vbString And Filepath <> Empty Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filepath)       'active file
        Union(Range("A1").EntireColumn, Range("C1:D1").EntireColumn, Range("Q1:T1").EntireColumn).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("A1")
        wb.Close
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "Incorrect Input, Please select the file again"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It'd be a good idea to explain why s/he should try this code, what differences have you made? (apart from using `EntireColumn`), why is this a better way of doing it?